# SQL - Selecting top result from query

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, join

I'm using the data below to grab a code of a TYPEID that either doesn't exist in table 2 or that exists and it not null in the RTURNDTE column.

I've managed where it's returning all the rows from table one that meet the criteria but i want it to only be returning one from the code column that 
meets the criteria and can't figure out how.

THE DATA:

TABLE1:

```
+-----------+----------+
|    CODE   |  TYPEID  |
+-----------+----------+
| 441       |  mn014   |
| 223       |  mn014   |
| 224       |  mn014   |
| 655       |  mn089   |
| 854       |  mn089   |
| 449       |  mn032   |
+-----------+----------+
```

TABLE2:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+
| CODE      | TAKENDTE | RTURNDTE |
+-----------+----------+----------+
| 441       | 25/08/14 | 01/01/15 |
| 223       | 25/08/14 | 03/01/15 |
| 223       | 25/08/14 | 01/02/15 |
| 223       | 25/08/14 |   NULL   |
| 655       | 25/08/14 | 07/01/15 |
| 854       | 25/08/14 |   NULL   |
| 449       | 25/08/14 | 06/01/15 |
+-----------+---------------------+
```

My Code:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where typeid = 'mn014' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.code = t.code and
                        t2.rturndte is null
                 );
```

Any help would be great, been stuck on this for hours, Thanks.

Comment: add `limit 1` at the end of your query

Comment: t1 not t in the not exist's where clause.